# How can a component understand that a variable has been overwritten from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got the App component this component have variable called test with empty value, I pass this variable to component Test in Test component on clicking the button I am changing value of test variable to hello, world! But how App component can understand that test variable was overwritten

```
export default function App() {
  let test = '';
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Test test={test} />
    </div>
  );
}


export default function Test({ test }) {
  function changeTest() {
    test = 'hello world!';
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={() => changeTest()}>Click</button>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good question, if you already know what is `prop`, you can treat an event as `prop` as well, in your case `changeTest`.

```
  const App = () => {
    const [test, changeTest] = useState('hello')
    return <Test test={test} changeTest={changeTest} />
```

in your Test

```
  const Test = ({ test, changeTest }) => {
    const onClick = () => { changeTest("world") }
    return <button onClick={onClick}>click</button>
  }
```

The reason you can't just do `let test = ''` is that if you do that, this variable is always fixed at `''`, since render function is called every time `App` component is rendered. That is why I used a `useState` to make sure I have a place to store `test` outside the render function. Please read more for Hooks.

Answer (score 0):

In React data is meant to flow from top to bottom. Please read about lifting state up [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

One way to do so is like @windmaomao mentioned which is ok for this simple setup. If for whatever reason you need to keep the state separated, you can use a library that provides observable objects. One example is [Mobx](https://mobx.js.org/README.html). You can then define the state as observable or computed, modify it in an action and track it in a variety of ways (wrapping the App component in an observer function would be the simplest here).